# How does `radon` in Matlab works?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to find the thickness of a segmented object that is in binary image. So I am trying to use 'radon' transform to find the intensity values with the value as "1" (white color) along the specified orientation. In this way i can find thickness at specified locations as I want. Before using this function `radon` I want to understand how it works. But I am not able to understand how radon works. As an example I took one simple image and coded as follows.

```
I = zeros(100,100);
I(1:25,1:25) = 1;
figure;imshow(I)
[R,xp] = radon(I, 90);
figure;plot(R)
```

I plotted `R` and checked for `theta = 90,0`. The plot shows impulse wave for both and there is a shift for `theta = 0`. The dimensions of `R` is `size(R) = 145`. How does `R` takes 145, when the size of image is only 100? How could even for `theta = 0`, `R` gives some intensity values? Can anyone give me a clear understanding on this `radon`?

Comment: Type `open radon` in matlab and you can inspect the code which might aid in your understanding. But basically the radon transform for a single angle is just the sum of lines across an image normal to that angle. So `radon(I, 0)` should be equivalent to either `sum(I)` or else to `sum(I,2)` and then `radon(I, 30)` should be pretty similar (conceptually) to `sum(imrotate(I, 30))`

Comment: Hey Dan, Thank you so very much for your answer.  I got the exact answer i want.

Comment: @ Dan, the code for radon.m does not help so much, because there is an intrenal function that doing all the job, called "radonc". I can't find it anywhere, do you know how to get it? or how it works?